Upper bound for difference of two call options

Let $r>0$ be the interest rate and $S_t$ the price of a stock at time $t$. Let $C(t,K_1),C(t,K_2)$ be the price of call options at time $t$ with the same underlying asset $S$, the same maturity $T$ and two different strike prices $K_1\leq K_2$.I want to show that $$|C(t,K_1)-C(t,K_2)|\leq (1+r)^{-(T-t)}|K_1-K_2|$$

My idea was to use the Put-Call-parity, I know that $$C(t,K_i)=P(t,K_i)+S_t-K_i(1+r)^{-(T-t)}$$ for $i=1,2$. Therefore
$$\begin{align*}|C(t,K_1)-C(t,K_2)|&=\left|P(t,K_1)+S_t-K_1(1+r)^{-(T-t)}-P(t,K_2)-S_t+K_2(1+r)^{-(T-t)}\right|\\
&=\left|P(t,K_1)-P(t,K_2)-K_1(1+r)^{-(T-t)}+K_2(1+r)^{-(T-t)}\right|\\
&\leq\left|P(t,K_1)-P(t,K_2)\right|+(1+r)^{-(T-t)}|K_1-K_2|
\end{align*}$$
but this is not what I want since I still get the $|P(t,K_1)-P(t,K_2)|$ in front. Can someone help me please?

I’m guessing this is a homework question— in your answer are you able to invoke something like risk-neutral pricing?

You almost got the solution, but try to write out the absolute value! If you think about the relation of the option prices you will notice that (by no-arbitrage):
$$C(t, K_1) \geq C(t, K_2) \, \text{ and}$$
$$P(t, K_1) \leq P(t, K_2).$$
This leads to the following (using Put-Call-parity)
\begin{align} |C(t, K_1) - C(t, K_2) |
&= C(t, K_1) - C(t, K_2) \\
&= P(t,K_1)+ S_t −K_1(1+r)^{-(T-t)} - \left(P(t,K_2)+ S_t −K_2(1+r)^{-(T-t)}\right) \\
&= P(t, K_1) - P(t, K_2) + (K_2 - K_1) (1+r)^{-(T-t)} \hspace{1cm} \text{ using } P(t, K_1) \leq P(t, K_2) \\
&\leq (K_2 - K_1) (1+r)^{-(T-t)}
= |K_1 - K_2| (1+r)^{-(T-t)}
\end{align}
Where the last line is due to $K_2 \geq K_1$.

Isn't $Payoff(call_{K2}) - payoff(call_{K1})<=K2-K1$  as RHS is the maximum possible payoff of LHS?
I think that solves it more easily
